# Reaction between chlorine gas and oxygen at 600 degrees Centigrade

Tags: thermodynamics, reactivity, chemical-engineering

Chlorine gas will not normally react with oxygen gas directly at STP. However, would the two react at standard pressure and 600 degrees Centigrade?

Comment: No.$\mathstrut$

Comment: Why always 600 degrees Celsius? There are several questions here that involve that specific temperature.

Comment: AP chem, apparently it's a common temp in our teacher's lectures and on the class practice sheets.